# How to create buttons in one page and show them on multiple pages,

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner at Html and CSS I have added buttons on my Html file and I want to show and use them on multiple pages, in other divs and classes with the same functionality, but after a lot of tries I am unable to do it can anyone help me? here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="pageone">
        <p id="line1">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Sint magni provident cum nemo dolorum non voluptatibus <br> amet alias quidem veniam facere nobis, excepturi, doloremque <br> tenetur dolore voluptatem quibusdam sapiente nam.</p>    
        <p id="line2">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Sint magni provident cum nemo dolorum non voluptatibus <br> amet alias quidem veniam facere nobis, excepturi, doloremque <br> tenetur dolore voluptatem quibusdam sapiente nam.</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="pagetwo">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button id="btn" type="submit" value="submit">Product</button>
            <button id="btn" type="submit" value="submit">Pricing</button>
            <button id="btn" type="submit" value="submit" >About</button>
            <button id="btn" type="submit" value="submit">Support</button>
            <button id="btn" type="submit" value="submit">Blog</button>
        </div>    
        <p id="line3">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Corporis distinctio eaque quae, voluptates illo pariatur <br> officiis, ratione eius minus rerum vitae, aliquam omnis <br> quam  suscipit  delectus dolorum deserunt cum animi. <br>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet .
    </div>
    <div class="pagethree">
        <span class="line"></span>
        <p id="line4">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Corporis distinctio eaque quae, voluptates illo pariatur <br> officiis, ratione eius minus rerum vitae, aliquam omnis <br> quam  suscipit  delectus dolorum deserunt cum animi. <br>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet .</p>
         <span>
         <img src="blank.jpg" alt="" id="logo1">
        </span>
        <p id="line5">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Corporis distinctio eaque quae, voluptates illo pariatur <br> officiis, ratione eius minus rerum vitae, aliquam omnis <br> quam  suscipit  delectus dolorum deserunt cum animi. <br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet .</p>
    </div>

        <div class="pagefour4">
            <p id="line6">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Corporis distinctio eaque quae, voluptates illo pariatur <br> officiis, ratione eius minus rerum vitae, aliquam omnis <br> quam  suscipit  delectus dolorum deserunt cum animi. <br></p>
             <span>
             <img src="blank.jpg" alt="" id="logo2">
            </span>
            <p id="line7">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Corporis distinctio eaque quae, voluptates illo pariatur <br> officiis, ratione eius minus rerum vitae, aliquam omnis <br> quam  suscipit  delectus dolorum deserunt cum animi. <br>
                </p>
                <hr id="hline"></hr>
        </div>
        </body>
       
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Note that IDs **must** be unique in a page

Comment: The navigation buttons? How do you expect them to work? Are they supposed to be links? Are they supposed to be activated by javascript? my guess is that you actually mean these buttons to be links, in which case, google HTML's <a> tag, and figure out how that works.

Comment: they are supposed to navigate to different sections using javascript

Answer (score 0):

There are ways this could be archived but unfortunetry it would require you to  use template engines, or frameworks like teact, or angular, but those are more advanced,

Your only option is to copy an paste the buttons on the different html files

Comment: what if I want to copy buttons with the same functionalities from one div to anotherr

Comment: You could generate them using javascript DOM and then append them to the diferent divs here is more or less how: https://sebhastian.com/javascript-create-button/